# Jquery Animation-Open dialogbox in a center?

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-animate

How can I open a dialogbox with jquery.animation() in a center of a screen and keep the alignment in the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery UI, dialog()

http://jqueryui.com